# Is Openni2 working with PCL?

Tags: ros, pcl, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've read somewhere that you can't use openni2 with pcl is that true ? I can't find any information that is not outdated.
The thing is had trouble installing openni while openni2 works on my computer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143936/is-openni2-working-with-pcl-?/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might also want to ask this on the PCL mailing list: http://pointclouds.org/contact.html - I can say that Openni2 works pretty well with ROS (openni2_camera package)

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2